# Adding materialize tooltip with ember JS template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, materialize

I have to add a materialize tooltip to an input in a form in Ember templates.

{{input class="card-panel grey lighten-3 form-field tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="I am tooltip" value=project_title id="project_title" placeholder="Project Title"}}

For this to work, I need to add

$(document).ready(function(){$('.tooltipped').tooltip({delay: 50});});

I am not able to understand where to add this code for the tooltip to show. I tried in the application_view.js in the views folder but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an initializer that reopens `TextSupport`. In **initializers/tooltip.js**:

```
export default {
  name: "tooltip",

  initialize: function(container){
    Ember.TextSupport.reopen({
      initTooltip: function(){
        if(this.$().is("[data-tooltip]")){
          this.$().tooltip({delay: 50});
        }
      }.on('didInsertElement')
    });
  }
};
```

Should work.